# Will the next MVC 6 be part of ASP.NET 4.6 or ASP.NET Core 1.0 or both?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am mostly interested in the unified Web API in MVC 6 for building restful services. However I am a bit confused at the moment on how these components fit together. When building a new app with the latest Visual Studio 2015, MVC 6 is available as an ASP.NET 5 template. My understanding is that ASP.NET 5 is now ASP.NET Core 1.0. What does this mean for MVC 6 and how will it be supported in the future? Will it be part of the ASP.NET Core 1.0, ASP.NET 4.6 or both?
Could someone please explain how these components fit together? Thanks!

Comment: OK found this link which clarifies things http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx

Comment: By the way I don't think my question merits a down vote. At the moment the whole situation is confusing. ASP.NET 5 becomes ASP.NET Core 1.0, but the tools as well as most links on the web still refer to it ASP.NET 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASP.NET Core is the unification of MVC and WebApi.

It can run on the .NET Core framework or on the .NET full desktop framework.

The MVC design pattern is still there but there is less reason to call it "MVC" when talking about it. In the old days we talked about "MVC" to distinguish it from other things like WebForms or WebPages, but ASP.NET Core doesn't have those other things so calling it "MVC" is not really necessary. It was earlier called "MVC 6" but that was before everything got renamed to ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Though you are right that MVC 6 as a term is dead, WebPages and SignalR probably will be moved to ASP.NET Core. About what the final names are, we just need to wait.

Answer (score 5):

You can find a good explanation here: [ASP.NET 5 is dead - Introducing ASP.NET Core 1.0 and .NET Core 1.0](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx)

In few words:

- ASP.NET 4.6 is the newest version of the ASP.NET we have known so far. This version is available right now.
- ASP.NET 5 was going to be the name of something that wasn't a newer version of the ASP.NET we've used so far. SO Microsoft decided to rename it as ASP.NET Core
- MVC 6 was the name of the MVC included in ASP.NET 5, so this name no longer make sense

One of the characteristics of ASP.NET Core is that, as you're asking, the MVC and Web API controllers are unified (which aren't on ASP.NET 4.6). But another very interesting thing is that ASP.NET Core runs on OSX, Linux and Windows, and there are available tools to develop thiskind of projects on these 3 platforms.

ASP.NET Core runs on .NET Core (previously named .NET 5), which is a "reduced" version of the .NET CLR that runs on OSX, Linux and Windows.

ASP.NET Core is already incomplete: it doesn't include SignalR or Web Pages so far, but it expected in the future.